# Connecting to Postgres running in a Docker container using psql

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis, psql, shapefile

I'm trying to run a local Postgres database with the PostGIS extension, and then populate the database with a shapefile, without having to load the data in manually.

I have a `docker-compose.yml` where I'm first using the postgis docker image and using port 5432. I've already tested this when the container is running and I can successfully connect.

The second part,  `import-shapefile` uses the postgres image and installs the needed extensions, converts the shapefile and should add the results into the db running in the postgis container.

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  postgis:
    image: postgis/postgis
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    platform: linux/amd64
    volumes:
      - ./dataset:/dataset

  import-shapefile:
    image: postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgis
    volumes:
      - ./dataset:/dataset
    entrypoint: sh
    command: -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgis && shp2pgsql -s 4326 -I -D -W UTF-8 dataset/my_shapefile.shp my_table | psql -U username -d my_db"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_DB
```

When looking at the container logs I see the error in the import-shapefile container:

```
sql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this within the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: You need to provide `psql` with the hostname or address of the postgres server, which is `postgis`: `psql -h postgis -U username -d my_db`. You will probably need to provide the password as well.

Answer (score 0):

your postgis host is the name of the postgis service, hence `postgis`

you need to add it as environment variable to your second container or use `psql` client inside the container such as:

`psql -h $POSTGRES_HOST -d $POSTGRES_DB -U $POSTGRES_USER`